# count number of users for past 7 days from a given date

Tags: sql-server, dateadd

I have table in which I have to update the number of users on that particular date and number of users in past 7 days from the given date. Sample data looks like

```
Date    UserCountToday  UserCount7days
20120911    907575  
20120910    953629  
20120909    1366180 
20120908    1388916 
20120907    1009425 
20120906    918638  
20120905    956770  
20120904    1018152 
20120903    1306341
```

Comment: sorry i dont udnerstand your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 with cte as 
        (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by [Date]) as row_num
        from t_users)
 select [Date],UserCountToday, (select SUM(UserCountToday) 
 from   cte c1 where c.row_num>=c1.row_num 
 and    abs(c.row_num-c1.row_num)<7)  as UserCount7days 
 from   cte c
```

**result**

```
Date    UserCountToday  UserCount7days
20120903    1306341 1306341
20120904    1018152 2324493
20120905    956770  3281263
20120906    918638  4199901
20120907    1009425 5209326
20120908    1388916 6598242
20120909    1366180 7964422
20120910    953629  7611710
20120911    907575  7501133
```

Comment: Do we have a more faster way to handle this? I have huge amount of Data. Dates range from today to past 18 months.

Comment: Its same kind of query, but i want distinct users for each period. Earlier, I had sum total the column UserCountToday for past 7 days, but it should be sum total of distinct users. I know i just need to put count(distinct userid) but its taking lot of time :(

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE as (select row_number() over (order by date) as rn,Date,UserCountToday,UserCount7days from tbl5)

,CTERec as (
select rn,Date,UserCountToday ,UserCountToday  as UserCount7days from CTE where rn=1
union all
select c.rn,c.Date,c.UserCountToday ,c.UserCountToday+c1.UserCount7days  as UserCount7days from CTERec c1 inner join CTE c
on c.rn=c1.rn+1 
)

select Date,UserCountToday,CASE WHEN rn<=7 then UserCount7days else (UserCount7days-(select UserCount7days from CTERec where rn=c.rn-7)) end asUserCount7days  from CTERec c
```