# average no of games per player in last week

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, average

How can I calculate the average number of games played per player for past week from a given date.
e.g. My table includes

```
DateId       UserId        GameId
30-aug-2012  3             89
31-aug-2012  2             32
1-sep-2012   1             53
1-sep-2012   2             56
1-sep-2012   1             32
7-sep-2012   3             56
```

So, result should be - (total games)/(total players) in week (1-sep-2012 to 7-sep-2012)
i.e. 3/3 = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select COUNT (distinct GameId)/COUNT(distinct UserId)
from   your_table
where  DateId>DATEADD(DD,-7,'7-sep-2012')
```

Comment: What if, if I have to do it for every date...like for DateId x, it should be between x-7 and x...for DateId x-1, it should be between (x-1)-7 and (x-1). I have to group data for past week from a given DateId.

Comment: @user1664644:sorry I dint get you.. you mean like a rolling 7 day window?

Comment: yup...i need to consider the past week from a given DateId. Its rolling week basically.

Comment: @user1664644 : `BETWEEN (x-1)-7 AND (x-1)` covers 8 days, not 7.  Also, are you requesting the ability to supply a parameter, and thus be able to query different weeks based on different parameters?  *(Please be specific, and include all relevant information in your question - not comments.)*

Comment: @user1664644: then did you try my  answer to your previous question ? what is the problem there? its almost same thing .. there //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401869/count-number-of-users-for-past-7-days-from-a-given-date